# How can I assume user 1000 inside of a docker container on linux?

Tags: fedora, docker, selinux

I am trying to use AFL++ to fuzz a target application on Fedora 36. I followed the instructions listed on [this page](https://github.com/alex-maleno/Fuzzing-Module#how-to-run-afl-on-exercise-1) by pulling down and running the AFL++ container and building it, and then creating the target container with the sourcecode of my target application mapped to the `/src/` directory in the container. Both containers are running fine. However, when I enter the target container and `cd /src/`, I cannot do anything in this directory because I get `access denied` errors. If I `whoami`, I am `root`. So I went `cd ..` and `ls -lha` and I see this: `drwxr-xr-x.   7 1000 1000 4.0K Jul 23 20:49 src`. I am very confused because A) I have no idea who uid 1000 is or why it's there, and B) I am root, so I have no idea how to proceed. I even tried `chown root:root ./src` and I get an AVC denial which states:

```
SELinux is preventing chown from setattr access on the directory postgres.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that chown should be allowed setattr access on the postgres directory by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'chown' --raw | audit2allow -M my-chown
# semodule -X 300 -i my-chown.pp

Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c9,c234
Target Context                unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0
Target Objects                postgres [ dir ]
Source                        chown
Source Path                   chown
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          localhost.localdomain
Source RPM Packages           
Target RPM Packages           
SELinux Policy RPM            selinux-policy-targeted-36.18-1.fc36.noarch
Local Policy RPM              selinux-policy-targeted-36.18-1.fc36.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     localhost.localdomain
Platform                      Linux localhost.localdomain 6.2.15-100.fc36.x86_64
                              #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu May 11 16:51:53 UTC
                              2023 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   3
First Seen                    2023-07-27 01:34:49 PDT
Last Seen                     2023-07-27 01:35:10 PDT
Local ID                      e862a3ed-4709-4cf4-89f5-9d3bf197af96

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1690446910.128:646): avc:  denied  { setattr } for  pid=49017 comm="chown" name="postgres" dev="dm-2" ino=1475147 scontext=system_u:system_r:container_t:s0:c9,c234 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0


Hash: chown,container_t,user_home_t,dir,setattr
```

When I execute `sudo  ausearch -c 'chown' --raw | audit2allow -M my-chown` I get:

`could not write output file: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'my-chown.te'`

Comment: Is the `/src/` directory mounted from the host into the container?  If so, that UID 1000 is from the host and the SELinux errors are from the host kernel.  You could either manage the permissions of that directory from the host to what you want them to be in the container, or you could apply the proper SELinux context to that directory to grant more access to the container.